# how to import a excel file from link in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I want to fetch an excel file from the server
but i have a warning message

> ### RNFetchBlob error when sending request : null

this is the code :

```
const url ='http://manafeth.ncsi.gov.om/admin/download/countries/import/2018/en?portTypes=land,air,sea&size=100000';
    RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            fileCache : true,
        })
        .fetch('GET', url)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())

        }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log('The error is ', err)
    }
```

)